# Custom XLOOKUP function to specify adjustments to the original lookup value if a match isn't found

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have deeply nested lookups so I thought to add an optional modifier parameter that would tell the function to adjust the lookup value and try again.

For example =VariableXLOOKUP(A1,B;B,C:C,-0.01) would look for A1 but if no match is found, it would look for A1-0.01.

I can replicate the normal XLookup function but I cannot get it to show results that require the use of the modifier. Ideally, I'd like to list as many modifiers in the function as I want but I am fine capping it at less than 10.

The first version I tried that would not show results that required the modifier:

```vb
Function VariableXLOOKUP(lookup_value As Variant, lookup_range As Range, return_range As Range, modifier As Variant) As Variant
    Dim result As Variant

    ' Try the initial lookup
    result = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(lookup_value, lookup_range, return_range)

    ' If no match and modifier is specified, try again with modified criteria
    If IsError(result) Then
        result = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(lookup_value + modifier, lookup_range, return_range)
    End If

    VariableXLOOKUP = result
End Function
```

Then I tried this version with the same results:

```vb
Function VariableXLOOKUP(lookup_value As Variant, lookup_range As Range, return_range As Range, ParamArray modifiers() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    ' Try the initial lookup
    result = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(lookup_value, lookup_range, return_range)

    ' If no match and modifiers are specified, try again with each modifier
    If IsError(result) And Not IsMissing(modifiers) Then
        For i = LBound(modifiers) To UBound(modifiers)
            result = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(lookup_value + modifiers(i), lookup_range, return_range)
            If Not IsError(result) Then Exit For ' Exit loop if a match is found
        Next i
    End If

    VariableXLOOKUP = result
End Function
```

I also tried a version that used Index and Match but in all iterations of this or the XLookup version, it seems to never return results from the loop part of the function.

I modified the code so the initial lookup is `result = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(lookup_value + modifier, lookup_range, return_range)` and it does return the results I expect (matches for lookup_value + modifier) so the issue is with error handling and moving on to the second lookup attempt as all lookup variations work if they are the initial lookup in the function but fail as soon as a second look is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```vb
Sub tester()
    Debug.Print VariableXLOOKUP(6, [A1:A10], [B1:B10])
    Debug.Print VariableXLOOKUP(6, [A1:A10], [B1:B10], -0.1)
    Debug.Print VariableXLOOKUP(6, [A1:A10], [B1:B10], -0.1, 0.1, 0.2)
End Sub

Function VariableXLOOKUP(lookup_value As Variant, lookup_range As Range, _
                         return_range As Range, ParamArray modifiers() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim result As Variant, x As Long, modVal

    result = Application.XLookup(lookup_value, lookup_range, return_range)

    If IsError(result) Then
        For x = LBound(modifiers) To UBound(modifiers)
            modVal = modifiers(x)
            Debug.Print "Using modifier: " & modVal
            result = Application.XLookup(lookup_value + modVal, _
                                                lookup_range, return_range)
            If Not IsError(result) Then Exit For 'got a match...
        Next x
    End If
    VariableXLOOKUP = IIf(IsError(result), "No match", result)
End Function
```

Dropping the `WorksheetFunction` allows the lookup to return an error value.

Using a paramarray allows you to pass in one or more modifiers to try if the original value isn't found.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-parameter-arrays